# How can I in matplotlib make graph from list of numbers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am new in programing. Could somebody hepl me with creating graph from list of numbers? To be more specific: read numbers from list and use them in y=x1*2 to create graph.
Thank you for answers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
root=Tk()

fig=Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)


class Win1:
    def start1():
        window1=tkinter.Toplevel()
        Label(window1, text="Zadej hodnoty x, pro které chceš vypočítat").grid(row=0)
        global e1
        e1=Entry(window1)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        fw=tkinter.Button(window1, text="vykresli",command=Win1.vykreli1)
        fw.grid(row=0,column=2)

    def vykreli1():
        get1=e1.get()
        x1=list(get1) #I made list of numbers from Entry
        y=x1*2
        plt.plot(x1,y)
        plt.show()

pica=Win1
f1=tkinter.Button(root, text="try1", command=pica.start1)
f2=tkinter.Button(root, text="try2")
f1.pack()
f2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `y = [x*2 for x in x1]`  or  `f = np.vectorize(lambda x:x*2)` and then `y = f(x1)`

Answer (score 0):

Hello there and welcome at stackoverflow.

You are faced with the following challenge:

The user enters some text. For example `5, 6, 12, 5.3`.
Your program reads this text in the line `get1 = e1.get()`. Now the variable `get1` becomes the string `"5, 6, 12, 5.3"`. But you need a list! You want to have a variable that equals `[5, 6, 12, 5.3]`.

This means you have to *parse* the string `get1` into a list of numbers. This is a very complex task! But there are good news: Python can do it for you!

Import the `ast` module. Use the function [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

You can apply it like this:

```py
x1 = ast.literal_eval(get1)
x1 = list(x1)
```

The second line `x1 = list(x1)` makes sure that `x1` is really a list. Because it is possible that the user enters just "5" and not "5,6".

Now we can calculate and plot the y values like this:

```py
ys = [x * 2 for x in x1]
plt.plot(xs, ys, marker=".")
```

It is also possible that the user makes other mistakes. He can enter something stupid like "5,hello!,7,8".

So we need some exception handling. I did this for you in the following example. I also renamed a few of your variables. And I am using some `print` statements to make it easier to understand what is going on.

```py
import ast
from tkinter import messagebox

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)


class Win1:
    def start1():
        window1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
        Label(window1, text="Zadej hodnoty x, pro které chceš vypočítat").grid(row=0)
        global e1
        e1 = Entry(window1)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        fw = tkinter.Button(window1, text="vykresli", command=Win1.vykreli1)
        fw.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def vykreli1():
        user_input = e1.get()

        print(f"user entered '{user_input}'")
        if not user_input.strip():
            messagebox.showerror("Missing entry", "You did not enter any text")
            return

        try:
            processed_user_input = ast.literal_eval(user_input)
            print(f"processed_user_input: {processed_user_input}")
            xs = list(processed_user_input)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"parsing error {e}")
            messagebox.showerror("Unparsable", "Please enter a list of numbers like 5,6.0,20,50.2")
            return

        ys = [x * 2 for x in xs]
        plt.plot(xs, ys, marker=".")

        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pica = Win1
    f1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="try1", command=pica.start1)
    f2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="try2")
    f1.pack()
    f2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I was able to start this program. I could enter a few numbers and then I saw a graph.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this answer solves your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. (The Marker is on the left side)